# TinyMCE: How do I remove a block format I previously selected from a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

When I have configured some block formats/styles which I then select from the Format dropdown, how can I remove/unselect/unapply them from my content so that the formatting is no longer applied to the given paragraph? Eg. I have `<h5 class="something">` that I need to have removed from the paragraph in the content.

I have tried to make another entry in the dropdown which is defined as just `[title: 'Regular']` (without any `block`, `inline` tags etc.) but selecting that doesn't do anything.

I also tried the `Clear formatting` button, but to my surprise that only removes the class, not the `<h5>` tag itself!

PS. I **not** talking about removing them from the dropdown menu, but how to remove them from the content in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness, is it really that simple. When you look at the dropdown you see a thick gray line on the left side for those formats that are applied to the current paragraph. And then you just choose the same format in the dropdown again - and it will be removed!